# How to disable tcp checksum offloading on OSX 10.11.6?

Tags: osx, tcp

I'm trying to deactivate the checksum offloading on OSX.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.link.ether.inet.apple_hwcksum_tx=0
--sysctl: oid 'net.link.ether.inet.apple_hwcksum_tx' is read only
```

This one above seems not to work anymore.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but have you tried disabling system integrity protection?
(I would have commented instead of giving this as an answer but my lack of reputation does not allow me to :( ).

Comment: Hi @till. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately disabling the system integrity protection did not solve the problem. For the instance, 
I ran ```csrutil enable``` in os-x recovery mode.